# how to use select option tags as an input in html using Django for backend

Tags: html, django

I have a simple form. This form consist of two inputs. Those inputs are post_city, and Category. Each one of them is a list. each list has a preselected choice, I want to use these selected items as an input for the form. It seems easy, but unfortunately, I could not figure it out. any body has an idea?.

Note: I want to keep dropdown items, so the user can change the preselected choice to another, and using javascript the search will updated dynamically.

Here is the html form for one select option:

```
    <form id="h_form" method="GET" action="{% url 'search' %}">


                  <span>
                        <li class="">



<select  form="hform" class="" onchange="this.form.submit()" >
                            <option value="{{post_city}}"> {{post_city}} 
                            </option>
                            {% for city in cities %}
                            {% if city.city_name != post_city %}
                             <option value="{{city.city_name}}"> {{city.city_name}}
                             </option> 
                             {% endif %}
                             {% endfor %}
                        </select>

                        </li>
                    </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should be something like this:

```
<option value="{{city.city_name}}" {% if city.city_name == 'the city' %}selected{% endif %}>
    {{city.city_name}}
</option>
```

Comment: This is true. However, the form is still does not pass any input

Comment: i think you should add `name` atrr to `select`

Comment: Yes. It works. I missed adding the name att to select